# Maven options in Eclipse disappeared

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I restarted my computer, and rebooted my VM with Ubuntu 12.04 on it and, I restarted Eclipse. Then I noticed that there were errors regarding the build, so I did a 'mvn clean install' on the repo in the terminal, and after that I re-imported the Maven project in Eclipse (when the option was still available). After the import finished I noticed that it said that mvn is missing the 'unpack' command in m2e. So I thought, that I needed to update the software so I went into Help > Check for Updates, and then I guess it found a better version of m2e, but now the 'Import Existing Maven Project' is gone now. I tried importing it regularly, however the 'src/java/main' and 'src/java/test' aren't distinguished as different special folders.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? If so, what did you do to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance,
ejay

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you right cliok the project and select Configure, does it offer to convert the project to Maven nature?

Generally, using the "clean" option on any tool will delete files and folders that are considered "secondary", i.e. they can be recreated easily. That might include some config files in this case.